# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphene_django' error when integrating GraphQL into the project

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, graphene-django

I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphene_django' error after I added 'graphene_django' in settings.py and run the python manage.py runserver command.
I installed django, graphene-django using pip but no use.
I tried with virtual env and with out too, got the same issue.

I followed the below article to build GraphQL and I got issue from Integrating Graphql into the project steps:
pip install graphene-django
added graphene_django to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py file
added endpoint steps in ecommerce/urls.py file
created schema, in the products/ directory with a file name schema.py
and run **python manage.py runserver** to test GraphQL API

see the output(python manage.py runserver) and error info:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/kalyan.avasarala/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphene-django'**
```

see the version details:
ecommerce % pip list
Package         Version

---

aniso8601       9.0.1
asgiref         3.5.2
Django          4.1.4
graphene        3.2.1
graphene-django 3.0.0
graphql-core    3.2.3
graphql-relay   3.2.0
pip             22.3.1
promise         2.3
setuptools      65.6.3
six             1.16.0
sqlparse        0.4.3
text-unidecode  1.3
wheel           0.38.4

I tried all the steps in the virtual environment (env). I tried creating same steps after I deleted e-commerce folder but not use and I tried to install django, graphene-django without virtual env too but no use.

Its on Mac laptop.

please share me steps or solution for the above issue.Thanks

Comment: Show your `INSTALLED_APPS`.